# Can't take a screenshot on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, images, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot in Lubuntu, but when i try to paste it on an image editor like GIMP it says "There is no image data in the clipboard to paste".

Comment: HOW are you trying to take a screenshot? What program are you using?

Comment: I have installed nothing i just use the screenshot key on my keyboard. But i could install Gnome Screenshot but it's weird that we can't save a screenshot by default.

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha you can use `scrot` but its not an interactive program

Answer (score 0):

"Using scrot
Install scrot with your package manager. On Debian and Ubuntu-like systems, type sudo apt-get install scrot. If your account isn't included in the sudoers file, first type su, type your password and afterwards type apt-get install scrot. On RPM-based systems who are using yum, type sudo yum install scrot. Same here about the sudoers file.
Run scrot (type scrot in your terminal)
Press the PrtScr-button. The screenshot will be in /home/user/." - https://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_take_screenshots